# Node.js - Stream Binary Data Straight from Request to Remote server

Tags: node.js, pdf, buffer

I've been trying to stream binary data (PDF, images, other resources) directly from a request to a remote server but have had no luck so far. To be clear, I don't want to write the document to any filesystem. The client (browser) will make a request to my node process which will subsequently make a `GET` request to a remote server and directly stream that data back to the client.

```
var request = require('request');

app.get('/message/:id', function(req, res) {

  // db call for specific id, etc.

  var options = {
    url: 'https://example.com/document.pdf',
    encoding: null
  };
  // First try - unsuccessful 
  request(options).pipe(res);

  // Second try - unsuccessful
  request(options, function (err, response, body) {
    var binaryData = body.toString('binary');
    res.header('content-type', 'application/pdf');
    res.send(binaryData);
  });

});
```

Putting both data and `binaryData` in a `console.log` show that the proper data is there but the subsequent PDF that is downloaded is corrupt. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, never mind. Found out Postman (Chrome App) was hijacking the request and response somehow. The `// First Try` example in my code excerpt works properly in browser.